# Time to Complete a Work

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to solve the following question:

> $15$ men and $16$ women together complete a piece of work in $6$ days.
> If $12$ women can complete the same project in $32$ days, in how many
> days will $10$ men complete the same project?
>
> $(a)~12\\(b)~20\\(c)~16\\(d)~8\\(e)~14$

Why is this approach incorrect ?

$15x+16y=\frac16\\
12y=\frac1{32}$

and solving...

Comment: As a 6 year member with >50 questions you should be able to format your question  properly, instead of posting a screenshot and relying on others to do the MathJax for you.

Comment: @MartinR sorry.. will do from now on ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This approach is correct but you need to understand what $x$ and $y$ signify: $x$ is the fraction of the work a man does in $1$ day, and $y$ is the corresponding fraction for a woman. Thus, $10$ men complete $10x$ of the work in $1$ day, and finish the entire job in $1/(10x)=12$ days.

Comment: Thanks..But solving the above equation does not yield correct results..

Comment: @techno $12$ is the correct answer, as obtained by these equations. If your textbook states some other answer, it could be an error.